# Correct filter function

Tags: python, function, filter

```
def isUpper(x):
    if ord(x)>64 and ord(x)<91:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isLower(x):
    if ord(x)>96 and ord(x)<123:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Having written the above functions, I now need to write the function letterSplit using only isUpper, isLower and the higher-order filter function.

I came up with:

```
def letterSplit(strng):
  if strng=='':
    return 0
  else:
    for x in strng:
        for y in strng:    
            filter(isUpper(x),strng)
            filter(isLower(y),strng)
    return (x,y)
```

The error that arises says bool obj not callable. Help me please
~Dont quite have a handle on the filter function

Comment: you should know that `.isupper()`, and `.islower()` are already string methods.

Comment: What are you trying to do here, split lowercase and uppercase letters?

Comment: @monkut this is almost definitely a homework assignment: "Having written the above functions, I now need to write the function letterSplit using only isUpper, isLower and the higher-order filter function."

Comment: what should `letterSplit` do, exactly?

Comment: I wish teachers using python would follow pep8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `isUpper` is your function, and `isUpper(x)` is a boolean value (`isUpper` evaluated with the argument as `x`).  Thus, you actually want seems to be this:

```
def letterSplit(strng):
  return (filter(isUpper,strng),filter(isLower,strng)) if strng else 0
```

more verbosely, this comes out to be:

```
def letterSplit(strng):
    if not strng:
        return 0
    uppers = filter(isUpper,strng)
    lowers = filter(isLower,strng)
    return uppers,lowers
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what the bool error meant, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question then I think you're trying to filter out uppercase and lowercase letters from a string.

```
def letterSplit(strs):
    if not strs: return
    else:
        #filter(isUpper,strs) is equivalent to "".join([x for x in strs if isUpper(x)])

        upper = filter(isUpper,strs)  #filter's first argument is simply function name
        lower = filter(isLower,strs)

        return upper, lower
        # in py3x filter returns an iterator, 
        # so you'll have to use "".join(upper), "".join(lower)

print letterSplit("SomeWeirdLookingStriNG")
```

**output:**

```
('SWLSNG', 'omeeirdookingtri')
```

**help** on `filter`:

```
>>> filter?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
Docstring:
filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string

Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.  If
function is None, return the items that are true.  If sequence is a tuple
or string, return the same type, else return a list.
```

Comment: This is right, do this.

Comment: from docs:  `If iterable is a string or a tuple, the result also has that type;`

Comment: @root thanks, I didn't knew that.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - Considering this isn't the case with `map` that is used more often, this is somewhat counterintuitive...

Comment: @root This has been fixed in py3x, where both return iterators.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Many thanks, especially with the help on filter.

Answer (score 1):

From the python docs( http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

`filter(function, iterable)`:

```
filter(isUpper(x),strng)
filter(isLower(y),strng)
```

`isUpper(x)` evaluates to a bool, not a function.

Instead, write

```
filter(isUpper,strng)
filter(isLower,strng)
```

Comment: `lambda x:isUpper(x)` is just a longer way of saying `isUpper`

Comment: @shx2 hmm. you're right. i'll update it

Comment: @shx2 they're not the same.  `lambda x:isUpper(x)` returns a function which returns the value of `isUpper`, but also adds an extra layer of work and overhead around it.

Comment: I guess a longer way means overhead

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand what `letterSplit` is supposed to do. Here's how you can use `filter` though:

```
Docstring:
filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string

Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.  If
function is None, return the items that are true.  If sequence is a tuple
or string, return the same type, else return a list.
```

---

```
In [1]: s = "Having written the above functions, I now need to write the function letterSplit using only isUpper, isLower and the higher-order filter function."

In [2]: def isLower(x):
   ...:     if ord(x)>96 and ord(x)<123:
   ...:         return True
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return False
   ...:     

In [3]: filter(isLower, s)
Out[3]: 'avingwrittentheabovefunctionsnowneedtowritethefunctionletterplitusingonlyispperisowerandthehigherorderfilterfunction'
```

Comment: Thanks for the filter help

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're doing here but you'll want to at the very least do:

```
filter(isUpper,strng)
filter(isLower,strng)
```

instead of:

```
filter(isUpper(x),strng)
filter(isLower(y),strng)
```

I believe you'll also want to get rid of those 2 for loops.

From the documentation:

> Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to [item for item in iterable if function(item)] if function is not None and [item for item in iterable if item] if function is None.